# UserIdentity is null after successful login and redirection to another razor view, ASP.NET Core MVC web application

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

This is the first time that I'm using the default `IdentityUser` to let users register and login into the application.

- ASP.NET Core 6
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
- Microsoft Entity Framework Core

Configuration is

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    // configure options for identity user
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    // Default User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();
```

App configuration

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

and in the controller I have

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginUser) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return View(loginUser);
    }   

    var result = await _signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginUser.Email,loginUser.Password, 
        isPersistent: false, false);  

    if (result.Succeeded) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
    // TODO: log error

    return View();
}
```

The result is `Succeeded` and I redirect to `Home/Index` right after successful login.

The cookie is created and I can see that in the development console in my browser.

In the `HomeController` I have

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index() 
{
    var loginUser = User.Identity.Name;

    MyEntity obj = new MyEntity ();
    return View(obj);
}
```

but `loginUser` is always null.

Also, when I try to use the `User` in `_layout` to display the login user, it's also null.

Most of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540896/asp-net-identity-user-null-after-login) [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1dbd601-880e-4189-821a-8a840532c6af/useridentityname-is-null-after-login-using-signinmanagerpasswordsigninasync?forum=aspdotnetcore) are to redirect right after signing to be able to get the user, but I always get a null user even after redirecting to another view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must add `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();` in `Program.cs` on *App configuration* section.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missed `UseAuthentication` (sorry for really short answer but I don't have enough points to comment)